# Bootstrap upgrade to latest version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, upgrade, hints

I'm creating website for the first time with latest (twitter) Bootstrap (v4.5).
I'm wondering what the best way is to update when a newer version is released. Also, is it better to implement Bootstrap by downloading the framework or just implement the CDN's?
Can it be so simple to update latest version just by updating links for Bootstrap? :)
Thanks in advance for feedback & tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow first of all,

Well to update / upgrade Bootstrap there are multiple ways.

If you just including the CDN links to your HTML it is possible to copy for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However when you using NPM for installing bootstrap to your website you can also use the **NPM UPDATE** command for updating dependancies to the latest version.

As far as I know Bootstrap 5v release is around the corner and for the use of classes is almost everything the same although you might look out for jQuery. jQuery is deleted in version 5.

**Update**:

About the question you ask for what is better to use; CDN or like an installer. I always prefer the installer above the CDN links, but that might be a preferring issue.

If you don't know how to use NPM?
For Windows or Mac you can install NodeJs with NPM now a days. Both installers can be found at:
https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm.

After installing both you can easily create a new project on your desktop and open a command-line and type in "**npm install bootstrap**
".

Comment: Thanks a milion for your help and time! 
I realized that I have a long way to go. Never mind, I go step by step. I'll study and try everything written so I will discover my preferences on my own.
Thanks again. Maybe one day, I'll help you out ;)

Comment: Hahaha who knows, glad my answer helped you! If you have questions, hit me up!